# Precedencia de operadores lógicos en el idioma español

Tags: conjunciones

Hoy he comido en un sitio que tenía un menú del día que advertía:

> Todos los menús van acompañados de refresco o cerveza y café o helado.

En muchos lenguajes de programación el operador `AND` tiene más precedencia que `OR`, y por tanto la frase se entendería como:

> Todos los menús van acompañados de (refresco) o (cerveza y café) o (helado).

Sin embargo, la idea que plantea el menú depende de que sabemos que, en primer lugar, están hablando de bebidas con las que acompañar la comida y, en segundo lugar, de cosas que tomar tras la misma. Luego en realidad la frase es:

> Todos los menús van acompañados de (refresco o cerveza) y (café o helado).

Así que en este caso la forma de resolver la frase está clara, pero en otros casos puede no estarlo. ¿Cuál sería la forma de redactar la frase para que no incurra en malinterpretaciones? ¿Existe alguna "precedencia de operadores lógicos" definida en el idioma español?

Comment: Gran pregunta, ojalá algún día se incluyan los paréntesis con esta finalidad :) A mí no me extrañaría ver algún bar usar una barra como "o" y escribir _Todos los menús van acompañados de refresco/cerveza y café/helado_

Comment: Hay otra forma de entender la frase, teniendo en cuenta que la conjunción *o* puede ser inclusiva puedo pedir las cuatro cosas :)

Comment: Would the careful use of commas help? ... refresco or cerveza, y ...

Comment: Los idiomas naturales no son lenguajes lógicos y creo que podríamos decir que son intrínsecamente ambiguos. No creo que predomine una conjunción sobre otra en tu ejemplo y se entiende bien en su contexto, en principio no creo que nadie tuviera dudas de como se tiene que interpretar.

Comment: @mdewey most probably. The use of a comma would act as the parentheses: _refresco o cerveza, y café o helado_ would act as _(refresco o cerveza) y (café o helado)_.

Comment: @blonfu eso lo comento ya en la pregunta, que dado el contexto en este caso se entiende, pero es posible que en otros no tanto. Por eso pregunto cómo se debe usar el lenguaje (que por supuesto que es algo ambiguo) para evitar estas ambigüedades.

Comment: En realidad iba a hacer una respuesta con eso pero los ejemplos para evitar la ambigüedad que me salían eran demasiado rebuscados y la forma de despejar las dudas en estos casos suele ser el propio contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a dejar de lado la precedencia de los operadores en la programación y paso a explicar de la mejor manera posible.

Es un poco dificil explicarlo, incluso me atrevo a decir que quizás el menú pudiera estar mal escrito (Al menos a mi no me apetecería que me dieran a escoger entre beber una cerveza o refresco, y después tomar un cafe o comer un helado, ¡Que rara combinación!).

Bueno, digamos que esto se trata de **opciones** y después de cada **`y`** tu tienes la opción de escoger lo que más te apetezca.

> Puedes escoger  tus enchiladas acompañadas de arroz o frijoles y
>   refresco o cerveza y café o helado.

En esta oración, tienes 3 opciones para escoger el acompañamiento de tus enchiladas.

---

> **¿Cuál sería la forma de redactar la frase para que no incurra en
>   malinterpretaciones?**

Creo que la mejor forma sería sustituyendo cada **`y`** por una **`coma`** y dejando la última **`y`** de la oración intacta. La coma representa una pausa más breve que la del punto, dando a entender que hay opciones.

> Puedes escoger  tus enchiladas acompañadas de arroz o frijoles,
>   refresco o cerveza y café o helado.

Lee esta última oración en voz alta, y entenderás a lo que me refiero.

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer la precedencia se va aplicando a los grupos menos desplazados en primer lugar y despues a los grupos mas desplazados, pero, en caso de que exista la ambigüedad y estemos usando un operador más de una vez debemos, de utilizar "la coma" o "el punto y coma":

- Para : (refresco) o (cerveza y café) o (helado) :

  > Refresco; cerveza y café o helado.
- Para : (refresco o cerveza) y (café o helado).

  > Refresco o cerveza y café o helado.

Comment: Tienes razon Walen, 
De hecho analizar la opcion ha hecho que este decidido a borrar mi respuesta, al parecer mas bien la precedencia de los operadores esta en base a agrupaciones de "Y" y "o" 

al parecer las agrupaciones pequeñas o que van seguidas tienen presedencia sobre aquellas mas desplazadas 

Por ejemplo: a( 3 o 4 o 5 y 6 o 7) b(3 y 4 y 5 o 6 y 7)

Comment: Has mencionado dos veces "los grupos menos desplazados", imagino que es una errata. En todo caso, ¿podrías elaborar un poco eso de los grupos más y menos desplazados? Parece una idea interesante pero no termino de entender lo que quieres decir.