# Conjunciones alternativas

Tags: conjunciones

Habiendo leído [esto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23883/17605), tengo una pregunta.

En finés tenemos conjunciónes alternativas para clarificar casos como

> (a y b) y (c y d)

Típicamente la palabra para 'y' es 'ja', pero puede también ser 'sekä' o 'ynnä'. El ejemplo arriba puede decirse:

> a ja b sekä c ja d

Podemos ir hasta:

> ((a y b) y (c y d)) y ((e y f) y (g y h))

Con:

> a ja b sekä c ja d ynnä e ja f sekä g ja h

También tenemos 'tai' y 'taikka' para 'o' y 'vai' y 'joko a tai b' para 'xor'. (La distinción entre 'tai' y 'vai' no es tan clara en verdad.)

Mi pregunta: ¿hay estructuras similares en español? No me refiero al caso 'o' vs. 'u'.

Comment: El orden no se respecte religiosamente y 'ynnä' es bastante raro, pero se puede utilizar.

Comment: Que sepa no.  Lo único sería prolongar (en el habla) la *y* que va entre los otros dos grupos, quizás también pronunciando un pelín más rápido los dos grupos.  Tampoco hay modelo histórico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existen propiamente conjunciones que cumplan la función de asociar más o menos fuertemente las frases. Existen, sí, algunas expresiones muy comunes que permiten agrupar o asociar de esta manera, y que para los fines prácticos funcionan como conjunciones. Se me ocurre, por ejemplo, *junto con*:

- *Hoy vienen a cenar papá y mamá junto con mi tía y su novio.*
- *Serviremos pollo y cerdo junto con ensaladas y puré.*

También se puede recurrir a utilizar adverbios como *además*, *también* luego de la conjunción *y*:

- *Vimos a mi amiga Ana y su esposo y además a Juan y Pedro.*

Se pueden organizar los grupos dentro de alguna estructura del tipo *tanto... como...* o *por un lado... por el otro...*:

- *Tanto el presidente y su comitiva como los ministros y secretarios se alojan en este hotel.*
- *Tenemos por un lado quesos y fiambres y por el otro frutos secos y especias.*

Por supuesto, una simple pausa puede servir también.